# JPG Images not displaying in IE and Firefox

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox

I'm having a weird problem and it's driving me crazy. The problem is that every jpg image is not displayed in IE and Firefox browsers, while displaying properly in Chrome and Opera. What could be the cause of this problem? In IE when trying to open a jpg image into a new tab, shows me a bunch of strange characters instead of showing me the image, in Mozilla it pops in the "Save image" insted of open it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: can you post some code?

Comment: Here's the website I'm talking about polishcitizenship.pl

Answer (score 0):

The server is sending images with `text/plain` MIME type.  The "strange characters" are the text form of the image bytes.

[image]

On a nginx server, add the following to `/etc/nginx/mime.types` to make sure it serves jpg files as an image.

```
types {
    image/jpeg        jpg;
}
```

For an Apache server, create an .htaccess file in the same directory as the images.  Add the line:

```
AddType image/jpeg .jpg
```

Comment: And what would be the next step in this situation? Thank you for helping me!

Comment: What server do you use?

Comment: @jonathanD That would be a separate question but off topic on SO. You need to ask that on serverfault.stackexchange.com

Comment: @3308310 is not my website, I'm just trying to help this guy, he has a virtual server from Plesk (Parallels?), but I don't know what type of server it is

Comment: @3308310 I've added the following in .htaccess file from the main WordPress root but nothing positive happened: <IfModule mod_mime.c>
 AddType image/jpeg .jpg .jpeg .jpe
</IfModule>

Comment: It must not be a apache server.  I have never used Plesk, but I found [this link](http://www.serverintellect.com/support/plesk/add-mime-type-to-domain-plesk/) about setting the MIME type of `.jpg` files.  If you still can't get the images to display correctly, I suggest you ask this on [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You got an JPG which uses CMYK instead of RGB encoding, and Firefox/IE choke on such files. You just need to convert the JPGs to RGB colorspace, or in Photoshop you can save image like " Save for web"

Comment: I can't open any of them in Photoshop. When I open an image with Notepad, on the begining is something like: WEBPVP8 .. seems that the imagea are in the WEBP format and JPG is the incorrect extension because I can't open it in Windows Photo Viewer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problematic plugin, it's called "EWWW Image Optimizer" which converts the JPG images to WebP format. They have an alternative rewriting in case the images are served from a CDN which seems to not be working yet.

Thank you for trying to help me!